# how to Dial a Number when clicked on the number in phonegap?

Tags: ios, database, html, cordova

I am working on a Project which fetch numbers from database and show in a list with name and number

i want i when user click on a number it call on that number i tryied many things but fail every time

```
st =st + "<tr> <td ><a href='#' class='ui-bar yellow' id='status_color"+(newarr[i][2])+"' onclick=\"<a href='tel:"+newarr[i][0]+">  id='disphn"+(newarr[i][2])+"' </a>");\"> </a> </td><td onclick=\"showpro("+(newarr[i][2])+");\"> <h4 id='disname"+(newarr[i][2])+"'><span> "+(newarr[i][2])+". </span> "+newarr[i][1]+"</h4> <h3 id='disphn"+(newarr[i][2])+"'>"+newarr[i][0]+"</h3> </td><td> <a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btnst' onclick=\"<a href='tel:"+newarr[i][0]+">  id='disphn"+(newarr[i][2])+"' </a>\">Contact</a> <a href='#'  class='ui-btn ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all' onclick=\"showedit("+(newarr[i][2])+");\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
```

call Tag

```
 <a href='tel:"+newarr[i][0]+">'"+newarr[i][0]+"</a>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have a silly mistake in your code try now this

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Here you are using double cots on phone number but you need to use out side of tel syntax..
For more details check apple's official site that have fully describe about this [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

Comment: Where to mention click

mean as on UI where user click

Comment: let me check

and give me an example for array call as mine

Comment: Try this for array but I am not sure about this ....    <a href="tel:"+newarr[i][0]"">"+newarr[i][0]"</a>